# Can't login users with observable nestJS

Tags: typescript, authentication, rxjs, observable, nestjs

I'm working on a nestJS api and more precisely on login an user. Here's the code :

Controller

```
  @Post('login')
  login(@Body() user: User): Observable<Object> {
    return this.userService.loginUser(user).pipe(
      map((jwt: string) => {
        return {
          access_token: jwt,
        };
      }),
    );
  }
```

Service

```
  /* Sign in an user*/
  loginUser(user: User): Observable<string> {
    return this.validateUser(user.email, user.password).pipe(
      switchMap((user) => {
        if (user) {
          return this.authService
            .generateJWT(user)
            .pipe(map((jwt: string) => jwt));
        } else {
          throw new UnauthorizedException('Invalid credentials');
        }
      }),
    );
  }

  /* Validate user credentials used for signin in*/
  validateUser(email: string, password: string): Observable<User> {
    return from(this.findOneUserByMail(email)).pipe(
      switchMap((user: User) =>
        this.authService.comparePasswords(password, user.password).pipe(
          map((match: boolean) => {
            if (match) {
              return user;
            } else {
              throw new UnauthorizedException('Invalid credentials');
            }
          }),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  /* Find an user by email*/
  findOneUserByMail(email: string): Observable<User> {
    return from(this.userRepository.findOne({ where: { email: email } }));
  }
```

Compare Password function

```
  comparePasswords(newPassword: string, passwortHash: string): Observable<any> {
    return from(bcrypt.compare(newPassword, passwortHash));
  }
```

So the issue is that i'm getting a internal server error on postman.

After a bit of researches i found out that the user isn't found quick enough in the validateUser function.

Then I'm comparing a password to something undefined so there's no way it works.

I tried to used .toPromise() but i'm getting more errors.

thanks for the help

Comment: I think you might get more success if you tag this post with `rxjs`

Comment: There is no such thing like "not quick enough" in the above construct. Are you sure the findOneUserByMail method actually finds a user?